# how to enable telerik dropdownlist

Tags: jquery, telerik, telerik-mvc

I have a telerik dropdownlist which is disables by default:

```
        <%= Html.Telerik().DropDownList().Name("YesNo").Enable(false)
        .Items(items => {
            items.Add().Text("").Value("");
            items.Add().Text("Yes").Value("Yes");
            items.Add().Text("No").Value("No");
                })%>
```

Now I want to enable it when someone selects "No" for another telerik dropdown:

```
        <%= Html.Telerik().DropDownList().Name("Validate")
        .Items(items => {
            items.Add().Text("").Value("");
            items.Add().Text("Yes").Value("Yes");
            items.Add().Text("No").Value("No");
                })            
        .ClientEvents(events =>
        {
            events.OnChange("Validate_OnChange");
        })%>
```

So I tried this jquery method to enable, but its not enabling the ddl:

```
function Validate_OnChange(e) {

if($("#Validate").val() == "No"){
     $('#YesNo').attr('Enable',true);
    }
}
```

rendered mark up for Validate DDL:

```
<div class="t-widget t-dropdown t-header" style="width:249px;" tabindex="0">
<div class="t-dropdown-wrap t-state-default">
<span class="t-input">&nbsp;
</span>
<span class="t-select">
<span class="t-icon t-arrow-down">select
</span>
</span>
</div>
<input id="Validate" name="Validate" style="display:none" type="text">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try with `removeAttr`.

```
function Validate_OnChange(e) {
   if($("#Validate").val() == "No"){ // Enable
      $("#YesNo").removeAttr("disabled");
   } else { // Disable
      $("#YesNo").attr("disabled", "disabled");
   }
}
```

### Updated

```
<%= Html.Telerik().DropDownList().Name("YesNo").Enable(false)
    .Items(items => {
        items.Add().Text("").Value("");
        items.Add().Text("Yes").Value("Yes");
        items.Add().Text("No").Value("No");
            })%>
<%= Html.Telerik().DropDownList().Name("Validate")
    .Items(items => {
        items.Add().Text("").Value("");
        items.Add().Text("Yes").Value("Yes");
        items.Add().Text("No").Value("No");
            })            
    .ClientEvents(events =>
    {
        events.OnChange("Validate_OnChange");
    })%>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function Validate_OnChange(e) {
        if ($("#Validate").val() == "No") {
            $("#YesNo").data("tDropDownList").enable();
        }
        else {
            $("#YesNo").data("tDropDownList").disable();
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Still the same, its a telerik dropdown list. not sure if "disabled" attribute will work on it. It has an "Enable()" method which takes bool vlaue to enable disable the ddl. Enable(true) or Enable(false)

Comment: I only have Kendo MVC Wrapper currently, so I cannot vertify it. Could you post the rendered mark up?

Comment: I updated my answer. Please note that Telerik MVC Extensions is deprecated. If you are creating a new web site, I recommend using Kendo UI MVC Wrapper.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Yes, NO more Telerik MVC. This was an existing project, didnt want to re-work all the controls just because Telerik thought of deprecating MVC extensions without even providing any support. No more Telerik for me, they might scrap off Kendo too

Comment: I figure out the DropDownList. I was using `tComboBox` wrong. Please look at the last updated one.

Answer (score 0):

Try using simple javascript

```
function Validate_OnChange(e) {
            var ddlValidate = $find('<%= Validate.ClientID %>');
            ddlValidate.disable();
}
```

Comment: I get an error 'object expected' on line 'var ddlValidate = $find('<%= Validate.ClientID %>');'

Comment: can u check the id of your dropdown using firebug...or else do u have the website hosted...so i cn have a look into it and tell whats the issue?

Comment: @ArunBertil the OP is ASP.Net MVC; your answer is for traditional ASP.Net.

Comment: @ArunBertil id=Validate